# check for value if found before adding it to my drop down list?

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, python

i have a drop down list that i add items to it,i ask the user to type in brand name and check first if that brand is already found on the drop down list if yes prints a message if no do some actions.
here is the code:

```
def add_brand(self,x):
     self.elem=self.driver.find_element_by_id('MainContent_txtBrand')
     self.elem.send_keys(x)
     self.txt=self.driver.find_element_by_id('MainContent_ddlBrand')
     self.brands=self.txt.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')           
     for i in self.brands:
            if i.text==x:                
                print('already found')
                break
            else:                
                print('this item is new')                
                self.driver.find_element_by_id('MainContent_hlSaveBrand').click()
                self.driver.find_element_by_id('MainContent_txtBrand').clear()
                break
```

and here is the code to call that function:

```
no=input('enter how many brands u want to add')
store.add_brand_model_item()
for i in range (0,no):
    koko=raw_input('plz enter brand name')
    store.add_brand(koko)
```

Comment: I think I understand the purpose of the code, but what is the question?

Comment: i need to check if the brand the user will enter is not listed in the DDL if listed a message "already found" will show up

Comment: when user enter any brand even it's a duplicated one it compares with only the first <option> in the DDL then it turns to run the else statement ,i want to loop over all DDL options first

Comment: Did you try inserting something like `print("x >"+x+"< i.text >"+i.text+"<")` before the if?

Comment: Somewhat confused about what this has to do with testing ?

Comment: @phil i'm tesing and trying to create some functions for me to learn python more.

Comment: @user246- x is the variable that holds the user entry and i.text represents the DDL item.text,i tried it it's the same result it ends up only checking the first DDL item and breaks

Comment: Welcome to SQA, engy. Please consider making this question more generic, so other people could learn from your question too. Not it is very specific, but you define better in what context your script could be useful, some scenario, that would more useful.

Comment: I think this is not really a testing question, it is a basic programming question.  Just the fact that you are using webdriver does not make it a test question.  You just need to debug your code.  Use the print statement as suggested by user246.

Comment: @SuchitParikh You're correct that simply using webdriver doesn't make it a testing question. However, because the Selenium proposal was merged into SQA, we do accept non-testing questions using Selenium and other testing tools, as the expert userbase to answer them are likely congregated here. I need to analyze the question still to determine if it's too basic or otherwise doesn't meet the criteria of a good question. If it is an invalid question, it won't be because of it not being testing related.

Comment: @SuchitParikh,@corsiKa i would like to thank you for the minutes you spent viewing my question and i know it's a basic programming question and the function i'm asking about is not test related . i am using webdriver for testing but during this i faced this problem,i wanted to know the programming concept of it to add it as a plus for me.thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled a lot but finally I found the solution. I know it's not the only solution, so if anyone has another point of view to solve this, please share as I mainly want to learn the Python language and testing.

```
 def add_brand(self,x):
    self.elem=self.driver.find_element_by_id('MainContent_txtBrand')
    self.elem.send_keys(x)
    self.txt=self.driver.find_element_by_id('MainContent_ddlBrand')
    brands=self.txt.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')
    items=[]
    for i in brands:            
        items.append(i.text)

    item=items.count(x)
    #print(item)
    #print(items)
    if item>=1:                    
        print('already found')
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('MainContent_txtBrand').clear()
    else:                
        print('this item is new')                
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('MainContent_hlSaveBrand').click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('MainContent_txtBrand').clear()
```

The list is like a magic salute to data structures.

Comment: i know that this function is like validating the entry to the application and this has nothing to do with testing as from testing prospective you shouldn't validate the entry yourself you should let the application show us what it has to detect the bugs.i was only trying some stuff with the webdriver.thanx for help every body